# Why does present conditional of avoir + dû translate English 'should have'?

Tags: étymologie

I am befuddled because `aurais` literally means 'would have'. Then *Tu `aurais` **dû*** literally means 'you `would have` **dû**''  — it is blindingly obvious that 'should' has not materialized, and the syntax has no place for 'should'. But then what does *dû* mean exactly?

> Note also that the English ‘should have’ is rendered by *aurait dû* plus an infinitive and not
> by a participle form of the main verb:
>
> > Tu **aurais dû** me dire (not *avoir dit) cela plus tôt.
> >
> > You **should have*** told me that before.

Roger Hawkins and Richard Towell, *French Grammar and Usage* (2015 4 edn), p 279.

I am NOT asking about conjugations. I know *aurais* is the [2SG.PRES.COND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_glossing_abbreviations) of *avoir*, and *dû* the PPRT of *devoir*.

### [Peter Shor](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49304) kindly put a spin on my question.

Your other question (about *j'aurais dû*) is actually a more interesting one. You can generally translate *je dois* by *I must*. And in English, *must* turns into *to have to* for tenses where *must* doesn't work. So you'd think that « j'aurais dû » would mean *I would have had to*. But it usually doesn't; it means *I should have*.

How can this be logicalized or rationalized?

Comment: *Du* is the past participle of *devoir*.  *Tu aurais dû* is past conditional of *devoir*. You can check a conjugation table. Plenty of them online.  [French Past conditional](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/french/french-ii/french-ii-conditional-mood-and-conditions/the-conditionnel-passe).

Comment: Just check how the conditional is formed in French: it "materializes" in the verb ending. In English it materializes in "should" or  "would" and since you have the past conditional as you can see in the conditional table past conditional is a compound tense:  *avoir* in the conditional+past participle of whatever verb you want to use . Your question is all about understanding how conjugation works. Languages use different systems and trying to make a word for word correspondence is not how it works. And you **are** asking: "But then what does dû mean exactly?" if you know then no use asking.

Comment: Your questions all show a lack of knowledge of French verbs and **are based on false premises**. Forget devoir for a moment. Think of all the others: Tu aurais joué/Tu aurais gagné/Tu aurais dit/Tu serais venu or arrivé. That's the pattern and devoir follows it exactly. conditional plus past participle. dû is the past participle of the verb devoir, which can only be translated as part of: aurais dû aller, aurais dû faire as, for example: should have gone, should have done.

Comment: Because French is not based on English.

Comment: I previously wrote two answers and decided it wasn't a good idea to explain modality between languages with limited examples. You just need to understand that in French *must/have to* can take two different forms. While we mostly translate must to devoir, we could also translate it to falloir depending on situations. You can reformulate "I should have done it", to "I would have had to do it if I would've considered it an obligation, but now I regret it". This awkward long expression is easily expressed with should, likewise it's easily expressed with devoir in French instead of falloir.